# how to implement multithreading for jframe

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using this code for implementing multithreading :

```
class Progress extends JFrame implements Runnable {
  Thread t;
JProgressBar current;
JTextArea out;
JButton find;
Thread runner;
JFrame tframe;
int num = 0;

public Progress() {
    t=new Thread(this,"Thread1");
    t.start();


}
public void run()
{
      tframe=new JFrame("Please wait");
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       JPanel pane = new JPanel();

    pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    current = new JProgressBar();
    //current.setValue(0);
    current.setStringPainted(true);
    current.setIndeterminate(true);

    pane.add(current);
    setContentPane(pane);
    tframe.add(pane);
    tframe.pack();
    tframe.setSize(300,100);

    tframe.setResizable(false);
    tframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    tframe.setLocation(300,300);
    tframe.setVisible(true);

}
public void stop()
{
    tframe.dispose();
}
```

When i need to start the thread, i use

```
     Progress t=new Progress(); .
```

This displays the frame , and to stop i use t.stop(); However, i am not getting the desired multithreading effect. Only the frame is displayed, not the inanimate progress bar . Note that, progress bar is displayed when used as a single thread;

What must be done here? Please help, Thanks in Advance

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  I am guessing all that source would need to become an SSCCE, is a `main(String[])` method and some imports.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely wrong. Swing is single-threaded. Every interaction with swing components must be done in the single, event dispatch, thread. Read [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) carefully. It explains how things must be done when working with multiple threads. Also read [this tutorial on progress bars and progress monitors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

Comment: -1: I'm a very sparse downvoter (only 27 out of over 1100 votes) but your answer is severely misleading. "This is completely wrong" It's not completely wrong. There may be flaws, but it's not completely wrong. "Swing is single-threaded" I don't know where to begin on that. That's simply... wrong! Swing is inherently multi-threaded, with support for numerous types of other, non-essential threads.

Comment: From http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading : "All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread". I didn't say anything else, and I pointed the OP to the official swing tutorial explaining how to work with multiple threads. Regarding the multithreading aspect, which this question is all about, the OP's code is indeed completely wrong. It might sound harsh, but it's a fact. And my answer is not misleading at all, since it leads the OP to the appropriate documentation.